# How can I check if a class name is present before executing jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I first check if a class name is present on a page before jQuery executes? I read you can use the length() method to check this. Right now my jQuery runs on every page and if the class name I want to alter is not on the page I get error. TypeError: 'oTable' of undefined or null reference. Below is my code.

```
    var oTable;
    jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
      'use strict';

    if ($('.mytable2').length > 0) {// Run the code below only if the class mytable2 exists

     // start datatable
    oTable = $('.mytable2').DataTable( {
        pageLength: 10,
        searching: true
     });
    // end datatable

    // start yadcf
    yadcf.init(oTable, 
     [
      {
       column_number : 0,
       filter_container_id: 'external_filter_container1',
       filter_default_label: 'Select',
       }
      ]
     );
    // end yadcf
    }}); // end ready function and if mytable2 exists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition should work. Although i can't see any `foo` in your code.

One other solution would be to use [hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/).

See below

```js
if ($(".my-class").length > 0) {
  console.log('class exists')
}

if ($("table").hasClass('my-class')) {
  console.log('table has class')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="my-class">
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry I should have said the error is  'TypeError: 'oTable' not 'foo'.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if a classname already exists **before** executing `jquery` (or even before loading `jquery`) use [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

For example:

```
if ( document.getElementsByClassName('mytable2').length ) {
    // class exists in document, handle accordingly
}
```

Comment: thats vanilla JS not jquery

Comment: @Nikos M. Thank you. Yuur way works too. See the example and watch the console. There are no errors. http://jsfiddle.net/Paul2167/gm62s5pk/12/

Comment: I noticed with your method or mine I can use any class name, and still not have an error. I tried this if ( document.getElementsByClassName('test').length ) {. How come it still works? Maybe cache.

Answer (score 0):

There is two solution for it.
1) you put your jquery reference in the head section of html document
2) or  put your current code in shared layout or your index page below